# What region should I choose when I host my database?

Tags: mongodb, mlab

I am using Amazon S3 service in my project and I put the region as shown below in my code:

```
region: 'ap-southeast-1',
```

because am from Malaysia and Singapore is the nearest.

Now I want to host my Database using [MongoLab](http://www.mlab.com) but they only provide 4 options for the region, as it is shown in the picture below

[image: MongoLab Regions]

Can I still host my database on MongoLab or should I look for an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Sydney would be the closest geo for you. Technically the turnaround time should not be *drastically* different. MLab is a pretty solid solution, as it's used by  a wide range of industry leaders. Considering that your Singapore AWS instance will be transacting with Sydney, it's not really that much of latency AFAIK

Singapore and Mumbai are fairly recent locations in AWS. You can hope for MLab open up data centers in SE Asia sometime soon considering the booming emerging economies and then migrate your data at that point. As of now, Sydney seems to be your best bet, if you want to go for a hosted solution

Comment: thanks for the input, one part I am confused of. Should I choose the AWS region am in, or the region where my potential customers will be?

Comment: Your AWS instance is going to to interacting with your Mongo instance. The latency will be determined by the proximity of your Mongo host to your AWS host. Obviously, because latency is also a function of the proximity of your customer to your AWS host, in the bigger scheme of things, you want to keep all of your servers as close as possible **to your customer**. Right now, _because you don't have a closer option_ you should probably go for Sydney. If MLabs opens a new data center in Singapore, you should go for that

Comment: i.e. your AWS host should be **closer to your customer**. Your MLabs host should be **as close as possible to your AWS host**, and by extension, your customer.